# How to play MP3 from Stream using DirectSound

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, playback, directsound

I'm writing a program which at some point downloads an MP3 and stores it into a byte array. Then I create Stream from the bytes.

Not sure how to play the Stream. I don't want to use any dlls except for DirectSound.

Are there any better ways to play the Stream? (not another dll)

If yes, how? And if not, how to play the Stream by DirectSound?

Comment: I would be seriously surprised if DirectSound can play MP3s. You are going to need something to convert the MP3 to a stream that DirectSound can handle.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b38936aa-da3a-4deb-8cf2-a890e89ac674/how-do-you-play-mp3s-in-directsound?forum=gametechnologiesdirectx101 here is a MSDN link that supports my comment

Comment: @MichaelCoxon So what approach do you recommend? There should be a standard/common way to do this.
I've worked with DirectShow before (on VB6) and it worked great with MP3s from files. What do you think about using DirectShow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible. See the quote from a similar [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b38936aa-da3a-4deb-8cf2-a890e89ac674/how-do-you-play-mp3s-in-directsound?forum=gametechnologiesdirectx101):

> Raw DirectSound isn't capable of playing mp3-compressed audio. I recommend using DirectShow for this purpose, as it supports a wide variety of formats. You could also use a streaming dsound buffer and do the decompression yourself, but this is probably overkill in your situation.
>
> Note that I don't recommend using mp3 in your project in any case, since it is not a royalty-free format. Ogg Vorbis is a good alternative.

Mp3 not royalty free so you will struggle to do it without a 3rd party lib and even so it is not recommended.

Comment: No worries about royalty freedom - there is a stock decoder in Windows. However DirectSound won't decompress on its own and won't accept raw MP3, so this should be solved by using other APIs.

Comment: @daniel-casserly Unfortunately I can't use other formats. My application downloads 30 secs MP3s through Spotify web API, so there's nothing I can change about it.

Comment: @RomanR. What other APIs do you think would work for me?
I've had use DirectShow before (with VB6) on MP3 files. Would it work with streams?

Comment: @RamtinSoltani: MP3 decoder is available in form factor of ACM codec, DirectShow filter, Media Foundation also embedded into Windows Media Format API. If you decided to have the byte stream in memory, ACM codec is possibly the best for you (even though you need to interface to it from C# code). DirectShow is fine, but to stream from memory you need a custom filter you don't have out of the box.